# python : concatenation variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have 3 `variable`

```
print(obj.col1_expense.text) #test1
print(obj.col2_expense.text) #test2
print(obj.col3_expense.text) #test3
```

how to print it dynamic?
now i am trying like this

```
    for x in range(1, 4):
        print("obj.col"+str(x)+"_expense".text)
```

But it gives **error**.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Read docs about `getattr()`

Comment: include `.text` extention inside the formatting like `print("obj.col"+str(x)+"_expense.text")`

Comment: You could also consider to use `eval("print(obj.col"+str(x)+"_expense.text)")`

Comment: @Sanket. won't work.  python does not provide for manufacturing variable names, at least not directly.

Comment: sorry @ShpielMeister, I won't able to understand what you were saying,  do you have any link??

Comment: @AmosEgel yes OP could.  not a good or robust approach, tho, especially for someone new to python.

Comment: @Sanket see comment by AmosEgel - it's not an ideal approach, and is brittle.

Comment: @Sanket I think the issue with your suggestion is that the string `"obj.col1_expense.text"` would be printed, but not the text stored in that variable ...

Comment: yes @AmosEgel  Got it, Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [[Python]: **getattr**(*object, name[, default]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
for x in range(1, 4):
    print(getattr(obj, "col{}_expense".format(x)).text)
```

or, to ensure you won't get `AttributeError` if messing up indexes, you could replace the `print` to this (not as easy to read) form:

```
print(getattr(getattr(obj, "col{}_expense".format(x), None), "text", None))
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you:

```
for x in range(1,4):
    col_text = 'col' + str(x) + '_expense'
    print(getattr(obj,col_text).text)
```

Comment: Quote `col` in the 2nd line.

Comment: @CristiFati Done.Thank you..!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if you want to create variables and corresponding values. 
It will depend where you want to use variables.

```
import pandas as pd
var = []
for x in range(1, 4):
    var.append("obj.col%s_expense.text" %(x))
print(var)
print(var[0])
print(var[1])
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
for x in range(1, 4):
    var = "obj.col"+str(x)+"_expense.text"      
    print(var)
```

Comment: won't work.   python does not provide for manufacturing variable names, at least not directly